# Word for a person who is taking/doing an exam?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for a person who is taking/doing an exam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cambridge examining board calls an **[examinee](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/examinee)** (someone who takes an exam) a **[candidate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/candidate)**.  If you need to be more specific, you can say an **exam candidate**.

> [What to say to candidates in an exam](http://www.cambridgeinternational.org/Images/183565-what-to-say-to-candidates-in-an-exam.pdf)
>   - *Make sure candidates are seated according to your
>   seating plan*.